# Difference between '(()) and (cons null null)

Tags: lisp, scheme

I am confused about the difference between '(()) and (cons null null) in scheme.

The code below show that `b` and `c` are completely the same thing.

```
(define (dup2 x)
  (let ((d '(())))
    (set-car! d (car x))
    (set-cdr! d (cdr x))
    d))

(define a '(1 2))

(define b (dup2 a))
(define c (dup2 a))

(set-car! b 2)

> c  ;; --> (2 2)
```

However, when I used `dup` instead of `dup2`:

```
(define (dup x)
  (let ((d (cons null null)))
    (set-car! d (car x))
    (set-cdr! d (cdr x))
    d))

(define a '(1 2))

(define b (dup a))
(define c (dup a))

(set-car! b 2)

> c  ;; --> (1 2)
```

Variable `b` and `c` are different. I have done some experiments, but I haven't understand yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unexpected persistence of data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18790192/unexpected-persistence-of-data).  The problem is because of the quoted data, not because of a difference in the values of `'(())` and `(cons null null)`.  Try replacing `'(())` with `(list '())` and you won't observe this problem anymore.  (That duplicate isn't Scheme, but Common Lisp, but the problem is the same.)  For even more fun, rather than making a `dup` procedure, try writing one that _pushes_ data into the list `d`, and you'll see the list getting longer and longer over multiple calls.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `d` in the first implementation is literal data, and is modified with undefined consequences.  To highlight what's happening, consider the following code:

```
(define (incorrect-list-null-and-x x)
  (let ((l '(())))                 ; a list of the form (() . ())
    (set-cdr! l (cons x (cdr l)))  ; (cdr l) is (), so (cons x (cdr l)) should be (x . ()) == (x), right?
                                   ; and now l should be (() . (x . ())) == (() x), right?
    l))
```

The expected result is that `(incorrect-list-null-and-x n)` should return a list of the form `(() n)`, and it does the first time, but successive calls are still accessing the *same* data:

```
(incorrect-list-null-and-x 1) ;=> (() 1)
(incorrect-list-null-and-x 2) ;=> (() 2 1)
(incorrect-list-null-and-x 3) ;=> (() 3 2 1)
(incorrect-list-null-and-x 4) ;=> (() 4 3 2 1)
```

The same problem manifests itself a bit differently in your `dup2`.  Every value returned from `dup2` is  actually the *same* pair:

```
(let* ((x (dup2 (cons 1 2)))
       (y (dup2 (cons 3 4))))
  (display x)
  (display y))
```

outputs:

```
(3 . 4)(3 . 4)
```

because the call `(dup2 (cons 3 4))` modifies the same structure that was previously returned by `(dup2 (cons 1 2))`.

Answer (score 0):

Data literals, like `'(())`, are meant to be read-only, and modifying it using `set-car!` or `set-cdr!` has undefined behaviour. For predictable behaviour, use the `(cons '() '())` version if you want to use `set-car!` or `set-cdr!` on it.

In particular, `cons` creates a new cons cell, whereas a data literal usually won't.

Still, for the purposes of implementing `dup`, why *are* you using `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` anyway? Just use `cons` directly:

```
 (define (dup x)
   (cons (car x) (cdr x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first code snippet you use `(d '(()))` which ends up binding a literal to `d`.  You then modify the literal which is generally undefined.  In your second code snippet you use `(d (cons null null))` which binds `d` to a newly created 'cons cell' which you then modify.  There is no problem modifying that.

Note: you've not defined `null`.  Perhaps you meant '()?

Comment: null is defined in scheme as '()  Edit: correction only in some implementations thanks

Comment: `(define null 'null)` is not a good assumption. The OP clearly intends `'(())` to be `equal?` to `(cons null null)`.

Comment: @DanielV Only in some implementations. It's not defined in the Scheme standards.