# Petite Chez Scheme (threaded) what is the difference between the two lists?

Tags: scheme, chez-scheme

In Petite Chez Scheme (threaded) . I defined two lists named myq and myqq.

```
(define make-queue 
  (lambda () 
    (let ((end (cons 'ignored '()))) 
      (cons end end)))) 

(define myqq (make-queue)) 
(define myq '((ignored) ignored)) 

;this shows myq and myqq are equal
(display (equal? myqq myq)) 
(newline) 

;test myqq
(display myqq) 
(newline) 
(set-car! (cdr myqq) 'b) 
(display myqq) 
(newline) 

;test myq
(display myq) 
(newline) 
(set-car! (cdr myq) 'b) 
(display myq) 
(newline)
```

this is the result:

```
#t 
((ignored) ignored) 
((b) b) 
((ignored) ignored) 
((ignored) b)
```

My question is: as the

```
(display (equal? myqq myq))
```

shows myq and myqq are equal.  Why do the same commands:

```
(set-car! (cdr myqq) 'b) 
(set-car! (cdr myq) 'b)
```

lead to a different result?
Plus, I don't know why `(set-car! (cdr myqq) 'b)` results in `((b) b)`.I think it should result in `((ignored) b)`, because we never change the car of myqq!

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but notice that it's typically not a good idea to modify literal (e.g., quoted) data: [Unexpected persistence of data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18790192/1281433)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `make-queue` is a structure consisting of *two* cons cells, not three:

- One cons cell contains `ignored` and `()` in `car` and `cdr` respectively.
- The other cons cell contains a link to the first cons cell in both its `car` and its `cdr`.

When you do `(set-car! (cdr myqq) 'b)`, you're changing the `car` of the first cons cell (because this is what is referenced in `(cdr myqq)`) from `ignored` to `b`.

`equal?` recursively checks pairs and similar structures, ultimately applying `eqv?` to the primitive values (in your case symbols). It doesn't count the fact that there is structural sharing between different components in `myqq`, and this isn't the case for `myq`, as a relevant difference.

`equal?` isn't the final word on equality, it's just one particular (and often useful) sense in which two structures can be equal. You can use other comparison functions to see that there's a difference between the two structures, e.g.:

```
>>> (eq? (car myqq) (cdr myqq))
#t 
>>> (eq? (car myq) (cdr myq))
#f
```

Comment: but what is the difference between myq and myqq?because via `equal?` they are the same.

Comment: @Pythoner No they aren't the same, it's just at that moment they have equal values.

Answer (score 2):

Equal? does not mean identical. Equal basicly asks are these two things values? If so are they the same? If they are lists of values, does each element of these list have the same value as to corresponding list.

```
 (define example 'ignored) 
 (equal? 'ignored example) -> #t  
 (set! example 'b) 
 (equal? 'ignored example) -> #f
```

That makes sense, right?

It has to do with the fact that cons cells are a pair of pointers.

When you define `myqq` you bind the name `end` to the value 'ignored, Which internally is a symbol, associated with a pointer pointing to some memory location with the value 'ignored.  When returning the value of `myqq`, it's a name pointing to a pair, this pair is is two pointer, both pointing to the same place that the pointer of end was pointing to. `set-cdr!` changes the value of the memory at the location pointed to by the cdr pointer. In the case of `myqq` this was also to location that the car was pointing to so you change both. In `myq` the `car` and `cdr` are each pointing to their own memory location loaded with the value 'ignored.

As pointed out by svk `eq?` will test equality by comparing pointers.

Comment: I like the code example in this.  It might be nice to show how it applies for structures, too, though.  E.g., `(define example (cons 1 2)) (equal? example (cons 1 2)) (set-car! ...) ...`.