# LISP: Why doesn't mapcan accept my list give as parameters?

Tags: list, parameters, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

To simplify my question:
why this works

```
(mapcan #'(lambda (l) (list '1 '2) ) '(a b))
```

and this doesn't

```
(mapcan #'(lambda (l) '(1 2) ) '(a b))
```

?

I have to write a function that substitutes an element through all elements of list D at all levels of a given list L, using Map Functions.
I tried using `mapcan` for this:

```
(defun subAll (l k d)
  (cond 
    ((and (atom l) (eq l k)) 
     d)
    ((and (atom l) (not (eq l k)))
     (cons l '()))
    (t (cons 
         (mapcan #'(lambda (l) (subAll l k d)) l)
         '()))))
```

but I get following results for these 2 inputs:

1.

```
(subAll '(1(2(3(4(5(6(7)))))) (2(3(4 7(4(4(4(4)))))))) '7 '(a b))
 => ((1(2(3(4(5(6(A B(4(4(4(4)))))))))) (2(3(4 A B(4(4(4(4)))))))))
```

2.

```
(subAll '(1 2 3 (4 2 (3 2 (2)))) '2 '(99 98))
=>Lisp stack overflow.
```

But if replace 
`((and (atom l) (eq l k))  d)` with `((and (atom l) (eq l k))  (list 'a 'b))` it works for input 1. Also I`ve made my own function that just deconstructs a list and reconstructs it:

```
(defun lst(l)
(cond
    ((null l) nil)
    (t (cons (car l) ( lst (cdr l))))))
```

and it work if a replace `((and (atom l) (eq l k))  d)` with `((and (atom l) (eq l k))  (lst d))` for both of my inputs above.

1. => `((1(2(3(4(5(6(A B)))))) (2(3(4 A B(4(4(4(4)))))))))`
2. => `((1 A B 3 (4 A B (3 A B (A B)))))`

Does mapcan accept only a special kind of list? If anyone can explain to me why it does that or give another solution I would be grateful. ( I can't use any built in functions like list or append, only if I make my own append and list)

I am using GNU CLISP 2.49

Comment: `eq` is probably not what you want. Try looking into `eql` or `equal`

Comment: You may find the answer to [Unexpected persistence of data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18790192/1281433) useful.  The short answer is that the quoted list in the non-working version is just *one* list that's getting modified over and over again.

Comment: Thank you, @Joshua. Very nice explained, really helped me understand more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

`mapcan` is destructive.

As per the [Hyperspec entry on `quote`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_quote.htm),

> "The consequences are [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if literal objects (including quoted objects) are destructively modified."

The easiest way to fix this is not to use `mapcan`.

```
(defun subAll (l k d)
  (cond 
    ((and (atom l) (eq l k)) 
     d)
    ((and (atom l) (not (eq l k)))
     (cons l '()))
    (t (cons 
         (loop for elem in l append (subAll elem k d))
         '()))))
```

with that definition,

```
CL-USER> (suball '(1 2 3 (4 2 (3 2 (2)))) '2 '(99 98))
((1 99 98 3 (4 99 98 (3 99 98 (99 98)))))
CL-USER>
```

**Long Answer:**

Let me get some style issues out of the way first.

---

Please [format your code properly](http://dept-info.labri.fr/~idurand/enseignement/lst-info/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html). It'll make it easier to read, both for you and people trying to help you.

```
(defun subAll (l k d)
  (cond 
    ((and (atom l) (eq l k)) 
     d)
    ((and (atom l) (not (eq l k)))
     (cons l '()))
    (t (cons 
         (mapcan #'(lambda (l) (subAll l k d)) l)
         '()))))
```

---

Next, the standard naming style for Common Lisp is `train-case`. Also, `(cons foo '())`, `(cons foo nil)` and `(list foo)` are all equivalent. You may as well use the shortest one. (You also don't *need* to sharp-quote `lambda` forms, though it doesn't particularly hurt).

```
(defun sub-all (l k d)
  (cond 
    ((and (atom l) (eq l k)) 
     d)
    ((atom l)
     (list l))
    (t (list (mapcan #'(lambda (l) (sub-all l k d)) l)))))
```

---

Lets take a look at what happens to your function as it runs during that `stack overflow` case.

```
; SLIME 2013-04-02
CL-USER> (defun sub-all (l k d)
  (cond 
    ((and (atom l) (eq l k)) 
     d)
    ((atom l)
     (list l))
    (t (list (mapcan #'(lambda (l) (sub-all l k d)) l)))))
;Compiler warnings :
;   In an anonymous lambda form inside SUB-ALL: Undefined function SUB-ALL
SUB-ALL
CL-USER> (trace sub-all)
NIL
CL-USER> (sub-all '(1 2 3 (4 2 (3 2 (2)))) '2 '(99 98))
0> Calling (SUB-ALL (1 2 3 (4 2 (3 2 (2)))) 2 (99 98)) 
 1> Calling (SUB-ALL 1 2 (99 98)) 
 <1 SUB-ALL returned (1)
 1> Calling (SUB-ALL 2 2 (99 98)) 
 <1 SUB-ALL returned (99 98)
 1> Calling (SUB-ALL 3 2 (99 98)) 
 <1 SUB-ALL returned (3)
 1> Calling (SUB-ALL (4 2 (3 2 (2))) 2 (99 98 3)) 
  2> Calling (SUB-ALL 4 2 (99 98 3)) 
  <2 SUB-ALL returned (4)
  2> Calling (SUB-ALL 2 2 (99 98 3)) 
  <2 SUB-ALL returned (99 98 3)
  2> Calling (SUB-ALL (3 2 (2)) 2 (99 98 3)) 
   3> Calling (SUB-ALL 3 2 (99 98 3)) 
   <3 SUB-ALL returned (3)
   3> Calling (SUB-ALL 2 2 (99 98 3)) 
   <3 SUB-ALL returned (99 98 3)
   3> Calling (SUB-ALL (2) 2 (99 98 3)) 
    4> Calling (SUB-ALL 2 2 (99 98 3)) 
    <4 SUB-ALL returned (99 98 3)
   <3 SUB-ALL returned ((99 98 3))
  <2 SUB-ALL returned ((3 99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 (99 98 3 ...
```

You never actually get to see the critical mutation point, but you can see an earlier equivalent (notice that by the second "layer" of calls, `d` is `(99 98 3)`, rather than the `(99 98)` that you passed in initially). At some point shortly after that, `d` becomes `(99 98 3 (2))`, at which point the loop goes infinite because you can find your target inside of your replacement. What I generally end up doing when I need `mapcan` is defining my own functional version.

```
(defun mappend (fn list)
  (loop for elem in list
     append (funcall fn elem)))

(defun sub-all (tree target replacement)
  (cond 
    ((and (atom tree) (eq tree target)) 
     replacement)
    ((atom tree)
     (list tree))
    (t (list 
         (mappend 
           (lambda (sub) 
             (sub-all sub target replacement))
           tree)))))
```

This also gets around the Undefined behavior for quoted lists. Specifically, with the above definition of `mappend`,

```
CL-USER> (mappend #'(lambda (l) '(1 2)) '(a b))
; in: MAPPEND #'(LAMBDA (L) '(1 2))
;     #'(LAMBDA (L) '(1 2))
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable L is defined but never used.
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
(1 2 1 2)
CL-USER> (mappend #'(lambda (l) (declare (ignore l)) '(1 2)) '(a b))
(1 2 1 2)
CL-USER>
```

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18790523/190887) (already linked by Joshua Taylor above) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very very much! It makes a lot more sense now.