# LISP: when modifying a list (with `nth`), all elements change

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Why, when I use `nth` to change a list element, do all elements change?

```
(setq mlist nil)
(loop for aa from 1 to 10 
    do
        (setq mlist (append mlist (list '(0 2))))
)
(print mlist)
(setf (nth 0 (nth 0 mlist)) 9)
(print mlist)
```

Expected result:

```
((9 2) (0 2) (0 2) (0 2) (0 2) (0 2) (0 2) (0 2) (0 2) (0 2))
```

Result I got:

```
((9 2) (9 2) (9 2) (9 2) (9 2) (9 2) (9 2) (9 2) (9 2) (9 2))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/578365/1848654

Comment: Your program contains only one `(0 2)` list. It's a piece of that program itself. When a program uses a piece of itself as a datum, that's a "literal".  If you evaluate the same piece two or more times, you get the same object: the same piece of the program.

Comment: @Xanthir's answer there says: The HyperSpec clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_quote.htm says behavior is undefined if the quoted object is destructively modified. It's implied that this is to allow impls to treat the values as atomic values - your '(0 2) is a quoted object.

Comment: change the inner `(list '(0 2))` to `(list (list 0 2))` - then it behaves as you want!

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/18790192/1281433